# swift IBDesignable view not show in storyboard

Tags: swift, uiview, ibdesignable

I want to custom a 5-star UIView,also I want it to be render in storyboard. So I decide to use @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable.The following is my code.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RatingView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setUpView()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setUpView()
    }

    func setUpView() {

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,50))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star")

        addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

And then in my storyboard , I pull a UIView into my canvas,and set Custom class to my custom view as RatingView.The compiler starts to compile storyboard file and I just wait for the custom view to be renderd in canvas.Here is the screenshot.
[image]

The state is "up to date",but the view has not been renderd.The view is just staying white,what I want to see is the image I add to the parent view.
When I use UILabel instead of UIImageView, the label is renderd in the canvas but not the UIImageView,how can I render my lovely star image in my canvas.(Images.xcassets has star.png file)

[image]

use UILabel instead of UIImageView

```
func setUpView() {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    label.text = "text"
    addSubview(label)
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Try to set the frame in your `setUpView()`, `UIView`'s frame is 0,0 by default

Comment: But UILabel did work...

Comment: Did you figure it  out?  I have the same problem - just white in Storyboard.  I have Files owner and Custom class set to the designable class.  It says Up to Date.  but nothing shows up.

Comment: I think the problem is that the image resource is not available at design time but at runtime,in WWDC2014,there is a session called What's new in interface builder (session411) talking about live render that might help you figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same exact thing. You need to put the view in a framework. As @Benson Tommy said in the comments take a look at WWDC 2014 session 411.

Here is a link to the session:https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#411

Here is a link to the transcript of the session: http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/411

Comment: This is not the case anymore. You don't need to put it in the framework.